# Indexing an Always Encrypted Column

Tags: sql, always-encrypted

I'm looking for a simple strategy to allow a column that has been encrypted via SQL2016 Always On to be sargable and indexed.  Consider the canonical use case where I have a credit reporting application that is storing SSN in an encrypted column using SQL 2016 Always Encrypted. I need to:

> Be able to index the column to provide quick searches, e.g. "Find a user by SSN".

In a perfect world you could do something like:

```
select FN, LN, SSN 
from Employee 
where SSN = encrypt(123456789)
```

or if unicorns and rainbows are involved

```
select FN, LN, SSN 
from Employee 
where SSN like encrypt(6789)
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

OK, after digging looks like I found my answer on this blog. Hope it helps others from having to find it.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2016/12/13/parameterization-for-always-encrypted-using-ssms-to-insert-into-update-and-filter-by-encrypted-columns/

Comment: Thanks I'm sure this is helpful, but pls paste in the juicy parts into your answer in case the link dies